# HyperLedger Fabric installation is hanging in the middle and not progressing in MacOS?

Tags: macos, curl, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to install HyperLedger Fabric on my System (MacOS Sierra 10.12.6) but I keep getting stuck.

According to this link (https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/install.html), I'm using this command: `curl -sSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/hyperledger/fabric/master/scripts/bootstrap.sh | bash -s 1.3.0-rc1`, however, it doesn't proceed after the first substep- as shown in the image below.

Strange thing is, it had proceeded past this stage in a previous attempt but had ended up getting stuck further along the way and not showing any output/update, so I terminated it and ran the same command in a adjacent directory (at the same location, in the same parent). Now its getting stuck here.

I've installed all requirements according to the documentation. Can anyone tell me whats going on? Why is my installation hanging and why am I not able to install the project?

Progress: 
[image]

Additional info:

```
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:BlockChain2 deepak$ docker --version
Docker version 18.06.1-ce, build e68fc7a
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:BlockChain2 deepak$ curl --version
curl 7.55.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin13.4.0) libcurl/7.55.1 OpenSSL/1.0.2o zlib/1.2.11 libssh2/1.8.0
Release-Date: 2017-08-14
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp scp sftp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy 
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:BlockChain2 deepak$ node --version
v8.11.4
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:BlockChain2 deepak$ npm --version
5.6.0
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:BlockChain2 deepak$ python --version
Python 2.7.14 :: Anaconda custom (64-bit)
Deepaks-MacBook-Air:BlockChain2 deepak$ go
-bash: go: command not found
```

also, in `~/.bash_profile` I've added the following:

```
# Manually added for HyperLedger Fabric Go installation
export GOPATH=$HOME/go
export PATH=$PATH:$GOPATH/bin
export PATH=/Users/deepak/Desktop/Project/BlockChain4/bin:$PATH
```

Each new iteration/installation attempt, I start in a new folder BlockChain, BlockChain2, BlockChain3, and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You seem to have an issue with pulling the docker images.
2. Unrelated to 1. How did you install go?

Comment: True! The issue was with docker, but noob as I'm to this world (programming), I just panicked and assumed everything was broken. I found a nice tutorial and ended up re-installing cURL and docker (the new file seemed to be larger than the original installation so it seemed like it could work) and it worked after that. Go was a standard installation, download compressed file, open, navigate dialog box. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UWhxiszSn74&t=210s. This was the video that I referred to, its largely the same, but going through it again helped me gain perspective.